# .htaccess and href links with uppercase and lowercase symbols

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting, hyperlink

I'm writing a url shortener which uses lowercase and uppercase characters.

I've written an intermediate script that helps me with analytics. This is in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   q.(.{5})\.example.com
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.example.com/this/r/%1
```

(url's changed ofcourse)

But somehow if the user navigates to **q.Fbbbc.example.com** he ends up at **http://www.example.com/this/fbbbc** (with lowercase F)

Any idea as how to fix this? A few clients of mine are already experiencing problems and I didn't think this rule would convert to lowercase..

As a related issue: In the frontend I use a basic `<a href="http://q.Fbbbc.dim.io">click</a>` to have users test the functionality, but in Google Chrome a hover over this link shows a lowercase url. The code in chrome really does show an uppercase F though... Any thoughts?

Comment: What's even worse. Bit.ly uses a same method but if you hover their links it actually shows uppercase characters too.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the rewrite - see http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: yes I did... nothing wrong. Could it have to do with the characters coming before the domain?

Comment: Try redirecting everything to index.php and then process it from there - just to see if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read the [RFC 3986 - Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). Specifically [Section 3.2.2. - Host](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2). You'll come across the following statement: `The host subcomponent is case-insensitive.`

In short: `'AA.ExAmPlE.Org' ===  'aa.example.org'`. Lower-Case being the dictated normalized form. If upper-case hostnames reach your script depends (at least) on (a) the browser, (b) intermediate proxies, (c) the http server. At least two components you have absolutely no control over.

If you want to make use of case-sensitivity, you'll have to move your slug (`Fbbbc`) to the pathname: `http://q.example.org/Fbbbc`.

Comment: Yes I did that :) As soon as I found out about the case-insensitivity. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

I've had a talk with our service provider and everything that is in your url before the first slash is considered lowercase. This way you cannot register APPLE.com when apple.com is registered. The same goes for subdomains; WWW.example.com is exactly the same as www.example.com. Lesson Learnt!

Comment: That is not entirely true. the hostname is considered lowercase. The userinfo component of the authority is case-sensitive.

Comment: what would be the userinfo component in this case? The summary is http(s)://aaa.bbb.ccc/xxx where a,b and c should be lowercase, x can be both.

Comment: your example doesn't have a userinfo component. `foo://a:b@example.org` contains the userinfo `a:b@`.